# Group Theory: Proof of the inner product formula.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

In algebra we saw the proof of the theorem stated below. I did not understand one of the last equalities. Let me explain and give the proof. First let me explain the notation.

Notation:

- Let $\leq$ be the subgroup symbol, i.e. $H \leq G \iff H$ is a
  subgroup of $G$.
- $|A| = n \iff$ The set $A$ has n elements.
- If $H \leq G$, then $[G:H]$ is the index of the subgroup $H$ in the group $G$.

> Theorem: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$, $K$ $\leq G$. Then $|HK|= \frac{|K| \cdot |H|}{|H \cap K |}.$

We proved this theorem in the lecture. But I don't understand the ending. Our proof goes as follows:

- Let $HK= \{hk : h \in H, k \in K \}$ and $hK= \{hk : k \in K \}$ for $h \in H$. Then one has that $HK = \bigcup_{h \in H}hK$ and $(H \cap K) \leq H$ (because $H$ is a group). Furthermore we have for $h_1 , h_2 \in H$ that $$h_1K=h_2K \iff h_1h_2^{-1} \in K \iff h_1h_2^{-1} \in H \cap K  .$$
  Thus one has $$|HK| = |\bigcup_{h \in H}hK| = [H:(H \cap K)] \cdot |K| = \frac{|H|}{|H \cap K|} \cdot |K|.$$

Now the part I do not understand is the equality $$|\bigcup_{h \in H}hK| = [H:(H \cap K)] \cdot |K|.$$
How do I see that this equality holds?

Answer (score 0):

When is it true that $h_1K=h_2K$? That's when $h_1{h_2}^{-1}\in K$, which is the same thing as saying that $h_1{h_2}^{-1}\in H\cap K$. So, when counting the elements of$$\bigcup_{h\in H}hK\text,$$
you don't really use each element of $H$, because then you would be counting the same element several times. Rather, you choose one single element of $h$ from each class of $H/(H\cap K)$. And there are $[H:H\cap K]$ such classes.

Comment: Oh so you say that I can construct a bijection between the sets $\{hK : h \in H \}$ and $\{h(H \cap K) : h \in H \}$ that is of course is surjective and because of $h_1K = h_2K \iff h_1(H \cap K) = h_2(H \cap K)$ one also has that it is injective. So therefore the sets have to have the same elements. Right?

Comment: @vaoy No. What I said is that if we want to count the number of elements of $\bigcup_{h\in H}hK$ then we need to avoid counting the same element twice and, in order to achieve that, we don't use *every* element of $H$; we just use *one* element from *each* class of $H/(H\cap K)$. And since there are $[H:H\cap K]$ such classes...

Comment: Ok so I understand why one has to avoide counting the elements more than onece, but I do not understand why there have to be $[H: H \cap K]$ this many cosets of the form $hK$ for $h \in H$?

Comment: @vaoy Try to think like this. In order to count the elements of $\bigcup_{h\in H}hK$, first you pick one element $h_1\in H$ and then you count the number of elements of $h_1K$; it has $|K|$ elements, of course. Now, you take an element $h_2\in H$.But you know that if $h_1(H\cap K)=h_2(H\cap K)$, then $h_1K=h_2K$. So you pick $h_2$ such that $h_1K\neq h_2K$, which means that $h_1(K\cap H)\neq h_2(H\cap K)$. And so on. In the end, you have $h_1,\ldots,h_n\in H$, where $n$ is the number of left cosets of $H\cap K$ in $H$. And so the cardinal of $\bigcup_{h\in H}hK$ is $n.|K|=[H:H\cap K].|K|$.